# remove first character in string

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have this script which takes the input and adds "ay" to the end and i also need to delete the first letter of each string which doesnt work. I tried using `.substring(1)` but it didnt work.

https://jsfiddle.net/kaibago/try07L8h/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#button").click(function(){
        var input=$("input[name=checkListItem]").val();
        var toAdd=input.split(" ");
        for(var i=0;i<toAdd.length;i++){
            toAdd[i]+=toAdd[i][0]+"ay";
            //toAdd[i]=toAdd[0].substring(1); does not work supposed to delete first letter of each string//
        };
    var output=toAdd.join(" ");
    $(".list").append("<div class='item'>"+output+"</div>");
    });
});
```

Comment: Try substring instead

Comment: You may be interested in using `Array.map` and/or a regular expression with replacement function as alternate methods of expressing the loop.

Comment: is there a way to move the first character in stead of removing it

Comment: nvm changed some stuf wrks now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[Working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/try07L8h/4/)**

Your code work fine after changing two things.

**First :** replace `subscript()` by `substring()`.

**Second :**

Instead of

```
//e.g : input='abcd', this will return 'abcdaay' (Note double 'a')
toAdd[i]+=toAdd[i][0]+"ay";
```

Use :

```
//e.g : input='abcd', this will return 'abcday'
toAdd[i]=toAdd[i]+"ay";
```

Because you don't need the `[0]` that select first character and also not use `+=` in this case because you want to rewrite the value and not append first character to it.

**Full code :**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#button").click(function(){
        var input=$("input[name=checkListItem]").val();
        var toAdd=input.split(" ");

        for(var i=0;i<toAdd.length;i++)
            toAdd[i] = (toAdd[i]+"ay").substring(1);

        $(".list").append("<div class='item'>"+toAdd.join(" ")+"</div>");
    });
});
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

`subscript()` isn't a function in JavaScript. What you're looking for is `substring()`.

```
toAdd[i] = toAdd[i].substring(1);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `slice`

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#button").click(function(){
        var input=$("input[name=checkListItem]").val();
        var toAdd=input.split(" ");
        for(var i=0;i<toAdd.length;i++){
            toAdd[i]+=toAdd[i][0]+"ay";
            toAdd[i].slice(1);
        };
    var output=toAdd.join(" ");
    $(".list").append("<div class='item'>"+output+"</div>");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The [substr](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substr) method should help you.

```
toAdd[i] += (toAdd[i][0]+"ay").substr(1);
```